# CSS Auto centering breaking

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I got this code and it's suppose to be for a footer (I appreciate suggestions as I'm a total newbie of website developing).

https://jsfiddle.net/rvcm4bwn/

```
.content {
   max-width: auto;
   margin: auto;
}
```

It's suppose to center the 3 elements of that ul and it works for the most part, but when the screen is really big (1900 I think, try also with more) then it breaks and it doesn't remains centered anymore.

**Bonus context:**
While trying to learn, I downloaded templates of footers to include in my website but they're unneccesary complex. What I want is just 3 centered sections/columns/divs/whatever to fill data in. And make sure they move to a single column if you resize the browser or you enter from a mobile.
This is more or less the layout that I want for my website: http://themes.89elements.com/definity-html/index-agency2-op.html
After spending hours researching, I'm still unable to figure out if the complexity of float stuff is worth it, if I should learn grid-layouts instead, for html5. Or scrap what I've done so far and start something else. I'm even considering to format my entire website with old school tables in order to avoid divs or css headaches.

**Edit:** This is for a Flask static website, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your issue is the specified grid behavior within this line:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(400px, 1fr));
```

There is [documentation for the property itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) as well as [`repeat()` function used to set the value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat). As you can see, your options are:

```
repeat( [ <positive-integer> | auto-fill | auto-fit ] , <track-list> )
```

And the easiest choice to achieve continued even scaling is to switch from `auto-fill` to `auto-fit`:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(400px, 1fr));
```

Comment: Hm... either I'm dumb or changing auto-fill to auto-fit still doesn't fix it.